# Eloquent - Select all fields from table where the value is not null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am having trouble to figure out how I can build an eloquent query that can fetch  all of the columns that are being filled. I am not looking for whereNotNull() and to manually write down all of the fields myself.

Is there a way that you can filter out all of the fields that are null?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Could you provide an example table and the output you would want from it?

Comment: Let's say I want to select the fore- and lastname from a relation, but only if neither of those fields is null. Without providing whereNotNull, I would like to retrieve the values.

Comment: @SanderPlomp, Do you want this - array_map('array_filter',User::get()->toArray()), this will remove all elements which has null value.

Answer (score 0):

By `all of the columns that are been filled`, I am assuming you are looking to pull all the rows where none of the column is null or empty. I ll suggest you do something like this:

```
    $user = new User();
    $table = $user->getTable();
    $columns  = \Schema::getColumnListing($table);
    foreach ($columns as $column) {
        $user->whereNotNull($column)->orWhere($column, "<>", "");
    }
    $user->get();
```